# Repeating alarm on specific days

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My application fires an intent twice, according to two set alarms, a start time and a stop time. I am now trying to expand on this so that the set alarms can be specified on multiple days, with the option of repeating.

I have 8 integer values received in a GCM on the target device, repeat = 1, sun = 1, mon = 1 etc ... if the day or repeat was selected, it has a value of 1.

How can I get the alarm to repeat on specific days ?

Can I put the received values, 0111110 would be all week days for example... then iterate through them and create the alarm where the value is a 1 ??

I am not sure how to structure this, could some one advise ?

Thanks.

Comment: Parse your response and then schedule an alarmanager according to the result

Comment: setup an everyday alarm, then when fired check the day or setup up to seven weelky alarms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, using the following ... maybe some one else will find this useful

```
             int[] daysOfWeek = new int[7]; 
             int[] daysOfWeekValue = new int[7]; 
             //parce from GCM values recieved
                    final int sunday = Integer.parseInt(sun);
                    daysOfWeek[0] = sunday; 
                    final int monday = Integer.parseInt(mon);
                    daysOfWeek[1] = monday; 
                    final int tuesday = Integer.parseInt(tue);
                    daysOfWeek[2] = tuesday; 
                    final int wednesday = Integer.parseInt(wed);
                    daysOfWeek[3] = wednesday; 
                    final int thursday = Integer.parseInt(thu);
                    daysOfWeek[4] = thursday; 
                    final int friday = Integer.parseInt(fri);
                    daysOfWeek[5] = friday; 
                    final int saturday  = Integer.parseInt(sat);
                    daysOfWeek[6] = saturday; 
                    final int repeating = Integer.parseInt(repeat);


                    daysOfWeekValue[0]=1; 
                    daysOfWeekValue[1]=2; 
                    daysOfWeekValue[2]=3; 
                    daysOfWeekValue[3]=4; 
                    daysOfWeekValue[4]=5; 
                    daysOfWeekValue[5]=6; 
                    daysOfWeekValue[6]=7; 

                    for (int i=0; i<daysOfWeek.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(daysOfWeek[i]==1){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Set alarm on day: " + daysOfWeekValue[i]);

                    final Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                    final Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, daysOfWeekValue[i]);// 1 for                      sunday, 2 for monday etc
                    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, starthour);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startmin);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    .....
```